# Const correctness for extern const pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to define constant strings that I can consume in a cpp file such that neither the data, nor the pointer can be modified. The linker complains the following:

> main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const *
>   const g_someString"

Sample code:

```
//constants.h
extern const char * const g_someString;

//constants.cpp
const char * const g_someString = "Hello";

// main.cpp
int main()
{
    strcmp(g_someString, "Hello");
}
```

This doesn't happen when the const char * const is replaced with const char * though. Is the compiler (MSVC 2015) optimizing out the g_someString definition in constants.cpp?

Comment: The linker error goes away with an _extern_ declaration before the definition in _constants.cpp_

Comment: make sure that `constants.cpp` includes `constants.h`  (and you don't have circular dependencies)

Comment: `void main` is illegal in C++, even if your compiler offers a non-conforming extension it's not good to write code that relies on such extensions

Comment: @M.M: I think maybe we should fix all those `void main`, *in addition to* commenting, in the cases where the problem isn't related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before

```
const char * const g_someString = "Hello";
```

you need to declare it as `extern` (e.g. by including the header), because `const` namespace level variables have internal linkage by default.

---

That said, you can just define the strings in the header. The separate compilation buys you the ability to modify strings without incurring a rebuild of lots of files, but apart from that, IMHO it's premature optimization.

---

To make string definitions in a header *formally* safe for `inline` functions, if that's desired, you need the strings (or least the pointers) to have `extern` linkage. One way to do that is to leverage a special exemption for templates in the One Definition Rule. E.g. like this:

```
// Perhaps best generated by some code generation facility:
template< class Dummy >
struct Strings_
{
    static char const* const some_string;
    static char const* const some_other_string;
};

template< class Dummy >
char const* const Strings_<Dummy>::some_string = "Blah!";

template< class Dummy >
char const* const Strings_<Dummy>::some_string = "Oh, well.";

using Strings = Strings_<void>;
```

Then usage like

```
inline void foo() { cout << Strings::some_string << endl; }
```

Here the `Strings::some_string` pointer will be the same in all translation units.

An alternative is to define the strings within an `inline` function. Then you can use e.g. an enumeration to name them.

```
enum String_id { some_string, some_other_string };

inline
auto strings( String_id const id )
    -> char const*
{
    switch( id )
    {
    case some_string:          return "Blah!";
    case some_other_string:    return "Oh, well.";
    }
    assert( false );    // Should never get here.
}
```

with usage like

```
inline void foo() { cout << strings( some_string ) << endl; }
```

The `inline` function has `extern` linkage, and so it's the same in all translation units.

Comment: Separate compilation can also help the compiler perform string pooling.

Comment: A pitfall with defining strings in the header is that if an `inline` function uses such a string, it causes undefined behaviour.  (Not to say that you shouldn't define strings in the header, just that one must be aware of this pitfall)

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, I didn't think of that (although I was aware of it at one time). I only thought about whether to mention how to do this in the header with external linkage, but decided that would just complicate the answer. Now I'm not so sure, hm. Anyway, to define the strings in a header and with external linkage, one can just use the old templated constant trick.

Comment: Could you post a link to an example of 'old templated constant trick' ?

Comment: @Karthik: SO is evidently not as a googleable as desired, because simple googling didn't turn up anything. And I've answered that umpteen times here. Although it may be google itself, because it's also been discussed in Usenet groups etc. Oh well, adding to this answer then.

Comment: Nice hack. I'd like to know the rationale for that rule about inline functions though.

Comment: @M.M: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. An inline function must have effectively the same definition in every translation unit where it's used. Essentially because the practical implementation is to discard all but one arbitrarily selected definition. And with internal linkage (pointers to) strings the inline function definitions using such a string will be different in different translation units. Anyway I think the template thing can be simplified with `constexpr`, avoiding the separate value definitions, but I leave it to others to check that.